# How can I call the Weblement to the other class

Tags: oop, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, assertion

```
public class LoginPagePages {
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//div[@class='validation-summary-errors text-danger']/ul/li")
    WebElement incorrect_username;
}
```

How can I pass the `WebElement incorrect_username;` to the class `LoginPageTestCase`, so that I can get its text into `String errorsign` and use it for my Assertion

```
public class LoginPageTestCase {

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void IncorrectPassword() {

        String errorsign = I NEED TO CALL HERE THE "WebElement incorrect_username".getText();

        Assert.assertEquals(errorsign, "Username is incorrect");
        Add_Log.info("Login Failed");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance of `LoginPagePages` in your test and use getter to get it

```
public class LoginPagePages {
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//div[@class='validation-summary-errors text-danger']/ul/li")
    private WebElement incorrect_username;

    public WebElement getIncorrectUsername {
        return incorrect_username;
    }
}

public class LoginPageTestCase {

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void IncorrectPassword() {

        LoginPagePages loginPage = new LoginPagePages();
        String errorsign = loginPage.getIncorrectUsername().getText();

        Assert.assertEquals(errorsign, "Username is incorrect");
        Add_Log.info("Login Failed");
    }
}
```